# Nginx - extract number from subdomain and use as proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I need to parse v111.site.com, extract the 111 and proxy_pass to 10.0.10.111 using nginx.

I tried the following setup, but the $zip seems empty in the logs.

```
server {
    server_name "~^v(?P<zip>9\d{3})\.site\.com$";
    location / { proxy_pass http://10.0.10.$zip:8009; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not match `v111.site.com`, because your first matching number in regex is `9`.

Maybe you meant to use

```
server_name "~^v(?P<zip>\d{3})\.site\.com$";
```